# Append a whole element which has children and grand children to another element using pure js

Tags: javascript

This is my placeholder div..

```
<div id="placeholderDiv">
</div>
```

This is my another div from which i have to get all the elements inside it

```
<div id="targetel">
   <div id="targetelInner">
     <a href="">one</a>
     <a href="">two</a>
     <a href="">three</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to get all the elements which are inside the id="targetel" and want to insert in to the id="placeholderDiv". and my final output should be

```
 <div id="placeholderDiv">
     <div id="targetelInner">
        <a href="">one</a>
        <a href="">two</a>
        <a href="">three</a>
      </div>
 </div>.
```

how can I code this using js..? and i write the html code in html document.. and not as a js file..

Answer (score 1):

just put the innerHTML of `targetel` to `placeholderDiv`

```
document.getElementById( "placeholderDiv" ).innerHTML = document.getElementById( "targetel" ).innerHTML;
```

if you want this to happen at `onload` event of the page then add this to your HTML page

```
<script>
    window.load = function(){
        document.getElementById( "placeholderDiv" ).innerHTML = document.getElementById( "targetel" ).innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

and remove items inside targetel by

```
document.getElementById( "targetel" ).innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Note that this removes any event listeners that were previously attached to the elements inside `targetel`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, No it will not remove any event listeners. Same events will not be triggered for elements which are appended in placeholderDiv`

Comment: @RayonDabre, you're misunderstanding my point. I'll post a separate answer that retains the state of the previous descendant elements.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Go on.. I repeat, __It will not remove any event listener from the earlier DOM__ OP has not mentioned anything related `events`

Comment: @gurvinder , Thank u much.. its working.. If i face any issue here after in this.. i will clarify.. :)

Comment: @gurvinde, At the same time i need to delete which are inside the id='targetel'

Comment: <div id="placeholderDiv">
     <div id="targetelInner">
        <a href="">one</a>
        <a href="">two</a>
        <a href="">three</a>
      </div>
 </div>.  and   <div id="targetel">
                           <div id="targetelInner">
                           <a href="">one</a>
                          <a href="">two</a>
                         <a href="">three</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>      ... my aim is after inserting need to empty the targetel

Comment: sorry.. I guessed. searching is there any other way.. Thank u friend.. :)

Comment: @HariharasuthanTG didn't get the issue. If you simply empty the `innerHTML` of the `targetel` like this `document.getElementById( "targetel" ).innerHTML = "";` why wouldn't this empty the `targetel`?

Comment: Hi.. its going clearly on UI.. but am writing  condition that after particular width of the screen i need to append all the elements which are inside the 'targetel' to the 'placeholderDiv'. else vise versa.. could please give any indea?

Comment: @HariharasuthanTG without proper markup or fiddle, it will be difficult to tell anything. Also, please post a separate question for the same, since this condition was not part of OP.

Answer (score 1):

This will retain the state of the elements that were in `targetel` and instead of copying the HTML markup, it transfers possession of the actual node objects. **Event listeners and other data will be kept on the elements transferred.**

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholderDiv');
var targetel = document.getElementById('targetel');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

while (targetel.firstChild) {
  frag.appendChild(targetel.removeChild(targetel.firstChild));
}

placeholder.appendChild(frag);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One of which, and probably the cleanest is to first get your element.

```
var element= document.getElementById('targetelInner');
```

Then create a clone of it. Note that specifying true in cloneNode will make it a deep clone, thus also cloning it's children.

```
var elClone= element.cloneNode(true);
```

After which you simply append the new cloned div.

```
document.getElementById('placeholderDiv').appendChild(elClone);
```

Note that append child will add this node as the last child of the placeholder, and not remove any contents it already has.

Comment: This does not keep event listeners of the original node either. See [Notes on MDN docs for `Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode#Notes)

Comment: thank you for the ideas.. i will folw and check.. :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The original answer didn't mention that the event listeners needed to be kept.

Comment: @GMchris that's not the point. The comment is for anyone who sees this answer to be aware of drawbacks.